# Using vis.js in Java on Eclipse with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vis.js

We are looking to invoke vis.js within our Java app/library through Maven in Eclipse. Any pointers would be helpful - what dependencies are needed and how do we access vis.js within Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the .js dependency through `org.webjars`  in Maven.  Add it to your pom.xml.

You could also use `npm` to manage your Javascript dependencies.

Accessing within Java is another matter.  You can always run using the Javascript engine built into the JDK (Rhino for JDK 7, Nashorn for JDK 8).

Comment: Thank you - I'm able to get the jar but can't figure out how to import the vis.js into my java code - I know i can use the javascript libraries in a js file, but something like

import org.webjars.visjs doesn't work

Comment: Import in Java is not about downloading anything. I'd recommend that you find a Nashorn tutorial.